# HTML object element's contentDocument is null but #document isn't

Tags: javascript, html

The `contentDocument` of my HTML document's `object` element is null during my document's `onload` handler.  The object element's content (from an SVG file) is drawn.  When I inspect the object element in Chrome's developer mode, I see that it has a `#document` property whose value is my SVG document.

The documentation for the `onload` handler suggests that the handler isn't run until all dependent content is loaded.  The SVG document clearly has been loaded into the `object` element, yet `contentDocument` is null.

```
document.getElementById("floor_plan_svg")

&lt;object id="floor_plan_svg" data="archives.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="Archive area at the Charles River Museum of Industry and Innovation."&gt;
        The floor plan or the archive area should appear below
&lt;/object&gt;

document.getElementById("floor_plan_svg").contentDocument

null
```

Why is the `contentDocument` property null in this case when I see it working in several of my very similar examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, even though an SVG file is loaded inside an ’’ element, the contentDocument property can be null during the ’onload’ event. This happens because the browser might not have finished setting up the ’contentDocument’ when the event fires

To work arround this issue, you can try adding a small delay using the "setTimeout" function inside your ’onload’ handler. This gives the browser enough time to set up the ’contentDocument’ before you access it.

Another option is to listen for the ’load’ event directly on the ’’ element itself instead of relying on the ’window.onload’ event. This ensures that the event is triggered specifically when the ’’ content is fully loaded.

I hope that this can help

Comment: Thanks.  You're suggesting listening for the "load" event on the `object` element?